# Show multiple y-axis in Kibana line chart

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I've two metrics that I want to display in line chart in Kibana.

Metric A has value range from 0-50, metric B has 0-2000.

Problem is when, suppose, Metric A is 10 and Metric B is 2000, line of Metric A is pushed down so much that it becomes imperceptible.

This is because Metric A is also shown with respect to 0-2000 range.

Is it possible to draw them in such a way that they are free from each other's scale?

Please suggest.

*Thanks*

Answer (score 0):

https://vkroz.github.io/kibana_cookbook/html/timelion.html#having-multiple-queries-on-the-same-chart

This should help. You can also consider using Vega/Vega-lite visualizations.